# Help on finding the radius of convergence of a series, analysis . Show it converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $E(X) = \Sigma_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$. 
Prove that the series defining $E(x)$ converges uniformly on any closed interval $[a,b]$

Attempt: by a theorem, let $S(x) = \Sigma_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x - x_0)^k$ be a power series centered at $x_0$. If $R = \frac{1}{lim_{k→\infty}|a_k|^{1/k}}$, with the convetion that $1/\infty = 0$ and $1/0 = \infty$, then $R$ is the radius of convergence of $S$. Then

ii) $S(x)$ converges uniformlu on any closed interval $[a,b]\subset (x_0 - R, x_0 + r)$.

Then  $R = \frac{1}{lim_{k→\infty}|a_k|^{1/k}} = \frac{1}{lim_{k→\infty}|\frac{1}{k!}|^{1/k}}$

I don't know how to simplify. Can someone please help me find the radius of convergence. The radius of convergence is suppose to be infinity. So I am supposing the denominator is suppose to approach zero so we would  have $R =1/0 = \infty$ right?
Any help would be really appreciate it.

Comment: There's an easy proposition which shows that we can use the ratio test (when it makes sense) to compute the radius of convergence of certain power series, since the root test is stronger than the ratio test.

Comment: if I find the radius of convergence using the ratio test, would I still be able to use the above theorem?

Comment: Yes. The ratio test evaluation gives you the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Weierstrass $M$-test. On the closed interval $[a,b]$, $$\left|\frac{x^k}{k!}\right| = \frac{|x|^k}{k!} \le \frac{c^k}{k!}, \quad c = \max\{|a|, |b|\}.$$

Since $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{c^k}{k!}$ converges (by the ratio test), the Weierstrass $M$-test ensures that $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.